# How to access/override defaults on parent's attribute in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following classes: `Item, StoneSword, IronSword, Apple, Steak`
Item is the parent class, and the Swords and food inherit the Item class. I want to have a bunch of different functions and descriptions for each of these classes. 
I completely understand the function side of things, but I am struggling to figure out how to override the default description with the children classes.

I am currently using single table inheritance with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to Mike Bayer for helping me figure out how to override `__init__()` to suit my needs. If anybody can find a more elegant solution, I will be glad to accept that answer instead.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, default="User")
    fullname = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user'
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(id={self.id}, name='{self.name}', fullname='{self.fullname}', email='{self.email}')>"

    def is_admin(self):
        print(f"I, {self.name}, am NOT an admin")


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("name", "Admin")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admin'
    }
```